# CGImageDestinationAddImage bug in iOS 11

Tags: ios, core-graphics, ios11

In an app, the following code just worked fine in iOS versions 9.3.5 - 10.3.x to convert an UIImage to a tiff:

```
func convertUIImageToTIFF(uiImage: UIImage) -> NSData {

    let propertiesTiff: [NSString: AnyObject] = [
        kCGImagePropertyTIFFXResolution: 200 as AnyObject,
        kCGImagePropertyTIFFYResolution: 200 as AnyObject,
        kCGImagePropertyTIFFCompression: 4 as AnyObject
    ]

    let properties: [NSString: AnyObject] = [
        kCGImagePropertyDepth: 1 as AnyObject,
        kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary: propertiesTiff as AnyObject
    ]

    let mutableData: CFMutableData = NSMutableData()

    if let imageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(mutableData, kUTTypeTIFF, 1, nil), let cgImage = uiImage.cgImage {
        CGImageDestinationAddImage(imageDestination, cgImage, properties as CFDictionary?)
        CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDestination)
    }

    return NSData(data: mutableData as Data)
}
```

This led to a NSData object that obviously was compressed which can be seen by its byte count (which was somewhere between 50kb and 220kb depending on the image content).

Since iOS 11 Beta (tested on Beta 9) adding the TIFF properties and applying the compression doesn't work anymore: the tiff files begin sent are about 8Mb and the XResolution header isn't included (in the data being sent to the server using Alamofire).

Any help is appreciated.

Update: the problem stills persists on Beta 10 and on GM.

Comment: We're seeing this fail to correctly generate an animated gif with transparent bg.

Comment: I also posted the question on the Apple Developer Forum with no response until today: [link]https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/258103#258103

Comment: Similar situation here. I was able to create gif's using similar code but in iOS 11 it just creates a blank image. Did you ever find a work around?

Comment: We are now making gifs without transparent backgrounds to get it to work. Also found that if we have enough frames (>13?) then it will work with transparent backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar issue and reported a bug to Apple with a link to this topic.